# value not matching while trying to find sum of values in a column using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I am trying to find the sum of values(negative & non-negative floating values) in a particular column of a text file and store in variable using awk. Tried this command

```
bal=`awk -F'|' '{sum += $48} END {printf "%f", sum}' filename`
```

*file is of 15GB size*

The output I am getting is 1168475137587.090576, the actual(expected) output should be 1168475137572.33, it is varying by 14.76, looking any better way of calculation for accurate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're having a floating point arithmetic issue. You could left-shift by, say, 3 chars (one more precision point than you need for your output apparently), sum using the integers that are the result of that, then right shift again and drop the last char or round however you like:

```
awk '
    { val=sprintf("%0.3f",$48); sub(/\./,"",val); sum+=val }
    END {sub(/...$/,".&",sum); printf "%0.2f\n", sum }
' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
1
1.1
1.12
1.123
1.1234
1.1239

$ awk '
   {
                                    printf "%s", $1
        val=sprintf("%0.3f",$1);    printf " -> %s", val
        sub(/\./,"",val);           printf " -> %s\n", val
        sum+=val
    }
    END { sub(/...$/,".&",sum); printf "%0.2f\n", sum }
 ' file
1 -> 1.000 -> 1000
1.1 -> 1.100 -> 1100
1.12 -> 1.120 -> 1120
1.123 -> 1.123 -> 1123
1.1234 -> 1.123 -> 1123
1.1239 -> 1.124 -> 1124
6.59
```

Comment: @Raviteja what output do you get when you run the script I posted on your input file?

Comment: Your script did work, made few changes to match my output, matched the expected value. `bal=`awk -F'|' '{val=sprintf("%019.3f", $48); sub(/\./,"",val); sum+=val } END { sub(/...$/,".&",sum); printf "%019.2f\n", sum }' filename` `